# How to open a folder in a new tab in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am a window user from the beginning but recently I started working on the **Linux** and there is one feature that I really like in **Linux** (off-course there are many more but I didn't use all thoroughly).

The feature I like is the **tabbing** in the system i.e. we can open a folder in a new tab so that we dont switch the windows again again.

Now I am return to the windows again but I miss the **tab** feature in the windows very badly. I have to open every folder in a new window which I dont like.

Can it be possible to do this in windows if possible than how.

Answer (score 5):

Windows doesn't support tabbed folders natively, but there are some Explorer addons or replacements that add this feature. I'm using QTTabBar and it works really well.

[image: Windows Explorer with QTTabBar installed]

QTTabBar doesn't replace Windows Explorer. Instead, it's injecting its modifications into its process. There's a ton of configuration options. You can, for example, configure Explorer to always work in one window that captures all other ones into tabs.

[Original QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/) isn't maintained anymore, but there's [a fork](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) that's still under active development and offers improved support for more recent versions of Windows.

Comment: A little investigation revealed that [Quizo](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) was the original developer, and the [sourceforge project](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/) was the fork. See [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/837975/16858) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Clover, an extension for Windows Explorer that does what you want.
Their website: http://ejie.me/

Comment: @MarkBooth yeah i know it will not cost me anything but dude I didn't see my post after that. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

As well as [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) and [Clover](http://ejie.me/) there is also [BrightExplorer](http://www.brightnewworlds.com/home/default.aspx?14).

Neither *Clover* nor *BrightExplorer* are open source though, so I will stick with *QTTabBar*.

Note that when [gronostaj](https://superuser.com/users/194694/gronostaj) mentions [*Original* and *Fork*](https://superuser.com/a/790100/16858), he has it the wrong way around.

The original developer was [Quizo](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com), but *Quizo* wasn't very quick off the mark updating *QTTabBar* to work with Windows 7, so Paul Accisano forked the project on [sourceforge](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/) in 2010. When *Quizo* started active devlopment again in 2012, Paul Accisano stopped developing, with the last published version being [v1.5.0.0 Beta 2](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/)).